# Windows won't start after hard shutdown; short dst fails but drive seems to be working

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, bios, hp-envy

I have an HP envy laptop (for about 3 years). Today, my computer froze up, so I ended up holding the power button to hard shut it down. However, upon trying to turn it on again, Windows [10] wouldn't load, stuck on a screen with a HP logo and a spinning circle. After waiting a long while, I shut it down (holding the power button), and tried turning it on again. I repeated this a few times (to no avail) (in retrospect, it probably might not have been the best idea).

This has actually happened once before, a few months ago. That time, I had done the same thing, attempted to take apart my computer and started unscrewing the screws, and then got lazy and tried turning the computer back on (with the screws unscrewed). It booted, but that was probably just dumb luck.

Afterwards, I went into f2 for diagnostics, and I found that the SMART test succeeded, but the Short DST check failed. Apparently, this means my hard drive had failed, and I needed a new one. However, booting into a linux LiveCD I had available, I found that my hard drive seems fine (at least, I can access the files fine). I also ran smartctl on /dev/sda and it seems fine.

I guessed that my MBR might be corrupted (from googling), but I'm no expert. What should I do to fix my computer? I don't have a recovery disk. Is it broken beyond all repair and should I make backups of all my files while I still can and then reinstall Windows?

Comment: A short DST fail is a bad hard drive. There is no further question about it. Get the data with that live Linux CD while you can and have the hard drive replaced and OS reloaded.

Comment: Bad drive does not mean data is gone, but it likely means data is in the process of going. It may still work well enough to get your data off of it, or to see data when using that linux live disk, but it isn't operating well enough (too many errors, to slow, etc) to run your OS. Like @Appleoddity said, back it up, and get yourself a new drive.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get I/O errors just from running ls. That's probably bad. For now, I've unmounted the drive; is there any way I can back it up (like with dd) without an external drive? I do have an external hard drive, but for some reason, it never shows up on my laptop. I was wondering if I could dd straight to digitalocean spaces or something.